# How could i relate Amazon EC2,S3 and my HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, hdfs

I am learning hadoop in a pseudo distributed mode,so not much aware of the cluster. So when browsed about cluster i get that S3 is a data storage device. And EC2 is a computing service,but couldn't understand the real use of it. Will my HDFS be available in S3. If yes when i was learning hive i came across moving data from HDFS to S3 and this is mentioned as a archival logic.

```
hadoop distcp /data/log_messages/2011/12/02 s3n://ourbucket/logs/2011/12/02
```

My HDFS is landed on S3 so how would it be beneficial? This might be silly but if some one could give me a overview that would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 is just storage, no computation is allowed. You can think S3 as a bucket which can hold data & you can retrieve data from it using there API.
If you are using AWS/EC2 then your hadoop cluster will be on AWS/EC2, it is different from S3. HDFS is just a file system in hadoop for maximizing input/output performance.

The command which you shared is **distributed copy**. It will copy data from your hdfs to S3. In short, EC2 will have HDFS as default file system in hadoop environment and you can move archive data or unused data to S3, as S3 storage is cheaper than EC2 machines.